# How do I get the x axis on top but keep a line on the bottom

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following plot

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
axis x line*=box]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-10:0,samples=40]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I want the x axis on top:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
axis x line*=top]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-10:0,samples=40
]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get the line in the bottom back?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line is there, but it might get confused with the border of the standalone image; you can give some value to `border` if you want to distinguish it clearly:

```
\documentclass[border = 1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
axis x line*=top]
\draw (axis description cs:0,0) -- (axis description cs:1,0); 
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-10:0,samples=40
]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `border=1pt` adds a little border (`1pt` wide) on the four sides; to add the border only on the bottom and left sides, use `border={0pt 1pt 1pt 0pt}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You seem only to want to move ticks. This can be achieved with `xtick pos=upper,xticklabel pos=upper`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$\sin x$,
xtick pos=upper,xticklabel pos=upper]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,
domain=-10:0,samples=40
]
{sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]